# Random selection from a heap of classes in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a best technique issue in Java. I have a base class implementing some genral methods. An a heap of inherited classes. Now I have to randomly select one of the inherited classes. My approach is the following:

1. Having a array of the *Class* object for each inherited class
2. Randomly generate an index for the array
3. Create an instance of the *class* object at the random index from 2. with *newInstance()*

Code exmaple for step 1:

`Class[] possibleClasses = {Class1.class, Class2.class}`

Is this a sufficient approach? For example the Eclipse Indigo syntax correction says for the code example above "Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized". So the definition without generic type may has side effects or so?

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine - indeed it's probably the simplest and most effective approach.

If you want to avoid the compiler warning you can add a generic type argument as follows:

```
Class<?>[] possibleClasses = new Class[]{Class1.class, Class2.class}
```

However this just gives you a different warning (unchecked conversion) so you might as well just suppress the original warning directly.

A slightly more complex alternative approach would be to use reflection to walk the class hierarchy and automatically add all subclasses of your base class to an ArrayList of classes. The advantage is that you wouldn't need to explicitly list out all the subclasses individually and it would automatically pick up any new subclasses added.

Comment: I don't think you code compiles. It should be: `Class<?>[] possibleClasses = {Class1.class, Class2.class}`

Comment: I think you need to cast the array in this instance to prevent the compiler from moaning about generic array creation.

Comment: When I use Class<Object> for the array's type, the compiler says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Class1> to Class<Object>".

Comment: @Adamski: I don't think this is necessary when you create the array with the initialization syntax like mikera does. It would be necessary if he had writen `new Class<?>[]{...}`.

Comment: @mikera: You line should read `Class<?>[] possibleClasses = {Class1.class, Class2.class}`, `Object<Object>` is wrong and your current code only compiles because the compiler creates a raw type and assigns it afterwards (you should get a warning about this).

Comment: works for me as defined above (you will need to suppress the unchecked conversion warning though).

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody has put this into an answer, I'll say it: use a `List`.  Arrays don't play nice with generic types.

```
List<Class<? extends MyBaseClass>> possibleClasses = Arrays.asList(Class1.class, Class2.class);
```

Before Java 7 this will produce a harmless warning:

```
Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter.
```

This can be safely ignored or suppressed, or you can instead do this:

```
List<Class<? extends MyBaseClass>> possibleClasses = new ArrayList<...>();
possibleClasses.add(Class1.class);
//...
```

And then you can generate a random index and use `possibleClasses.get(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class<? extends Collection>[] klazzes =
  (Class<Collection>[]) new Class[]{ List.class, Set.class };
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, people seem to have a really hard time coming up with the code. You should do something like this:

```
Class<?>[] cls = {Class1.class, Class2.class};
Random r = new Random();
Class<?> = cls[r.nextInt(cls.length)];
```

You should reuse the instance of Random from call to call to ensure distribution.